# Locally and countably compact $T_1$ space is normal

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A space is locally compact if every point has some compact neighborhood; it is countably compact if it's a union of a countable number of compact sets. $T_1$ is equivalent to that every singleton is a closed set, while a normal space separates its disjunctive closed sets with disjunctive open neighborhoods.

Using those definition it is stated that locally and countably compact $T_1$ space is normal. I failed to find a proof for this or derive one.

Comment: Your definition of "countably compact" is very unusal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-compact_space. Moreover, it seems that "locally compact" does not include Hausdorff. So what is your definition of "locally compact" and "compact"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't find the result because your definition of countably compact is not the classical one. What you state to be countably compact is referred to as $\sigma$-compact. Here you can find the proof that ever locally compact and $\sigma$-compact space is paracompact and, hence, normal by Dieudonné theorem.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+compact+and+sigma-compact+spaces+are+paracompact

However, double-check if their definition of local compactness matches with yours (usually there are many definitions, but they all agree when the topological space is $T_2$).

Answer (score 3):

This is *false* as stated: $X=\Bbb N$ in the cofinite topology is $T_1$, compact (so certainly "countably compact" (in your definition, better is to use the more standard $\sigma$-compact) and "locally compact") but not normal as it is not even Hausdorff.

It becomes true if we change $T_1$ to Hausdorff, though.

Comment: Well the deduction not Hausdorff therefore not normal is dangerous. Often one distinguishes between a normal space and a T4 space.

Comment: @Kosh we have a $T_1$ space in this context so I felt free to use it.

Comment: I agree, just wanted to point out this to the OP. Maybe let's write it down: Normal plus T1 equivalent to Normal plus T2, equivalent to T4.